# Calling C++ function with ctypes returns different results when compiling with qmake vs. GCC

Tags: python, c++, gcc, ctypes, qmake

I am working on a project that requires interfacing a C++ library with Python using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), like in [this tutorial](https://coderslegacy.com/structs-with-python-ctypes/) (Disclaimer: I know that ctypes is originally meant to be used with C, not C++). I am running some tests with [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/), which are successful when I compile the C++ library with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/).

C++ code:

```
// clibrary.cpp

#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

extern "C" struct Point *getPoint(struct Point point_a) {
    struct Point point_result;
    struct Point *ptr;
    ptr = &point_result;

    ptr->x = point_a.x + 10;
    ptr->y = point_a.y + 10;
    return ptr;
}

extern "C" void printPoint(struct Point p) {
        printf("%d %d\n", p.x, p.y);
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation from command line:

```
gcc -shared -o /Users/guadi/wrapper/src/clibrary.so /Users/guadi/wrapper/src/clibrary.cpp
```

Python code:

```
# structs.py

import ctypes


class Point(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", ctypes.c_int),
                ("y", ctypes.c_int)]
```

```
# test_clibrary.py

import ctypes
from ctypes import CDLL
from ctypes.util import find_library

import pytest

from src.compiler import compile_lib, SRC
from src.structs import Point


def test_get_point(capsys):
    source = "/Users/guadi/wrapper/src/clibrary.so"
    cdll = CDLL(source)
    cdll.getPoint.restype = ctypes.POINTER(Point)
    cdll.getPoint.argtypes = (Point,)

    point_a = Point(10, 20)
    p = cdll.getPoint(point_a)

    # Print point members and assert values are right
    print(p.contents.x, p.contents.y)
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    assert captured.out == "20 30\n"
```

I want to use [qmake](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-manual.html) for the compilation instead of GCC, because it integrates smoothly with [QT](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-index.html) and I need to introduce this tool in the future. However, the tests fail after compilation with qmake. I get zero values for `p.contents.x` and `p.contents.y`:

```
AssertionError: assert '0 0\n' == '20 30\n'
```

Compilation from command line:

```
 qmake src/clibrary.pro && make
```

Project file `clibrary.pro` used for compilation:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
QT += core
SOURCES += clibrary.cpp
```

In `test_clibrary.py` I change only the following line:

```
source = find_library("clibrary")
```

I am using MacOS, in case that happens to be relevant.

Why is the program behaving differently if I compile it with qmake instead of GCC?

Comment: Your tests fail because your `getPoint` function returns a pointer to a local variable. Dereferencing that pointer is undefined behaviour.

Comment: **You don't compile *C(++)* code with *QMake***, which is a *Make* (like) system and will use a *C* compiler (likely *GCC*) to compile *.c* source files.